acceso denegado el puerto com
Estoy intentando conectar una báscula/balanza con visual studio c#, pero cuando intento correr la aplicación sale un mensaje de acceso denegado a COM3
este es el código que estoy usando
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM3";
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
        serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
        serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
        serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
        serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(mySerialPort_DataReceived);
        serialPort1.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private static void mySerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
    Console.Write(indata);
}


Primeramente, debes asegurar que estás conectado a COM3 y ejecutar tu app con permisos de administador.

el com3 esta conectado inlcuso tengo una excepcion que dice si el puerto no existe pero cuando la intento conectar el catch (Exception ex) me dice que no se puede acceder al puerto tendre que configurar algo dentro mi equipo ...?

Deberías agregar en tu pregunta exactamente lo que muestra al "atrapar" el error en el "Catch"
